# Select old records in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want the oldest row by date for each Distinct Number. I created this script but the problem is I keep on getting the newest record.

```
SELECT*
FROM
     [Data].[dbo].[IAPT] t1
WHERE
      [Last Contact Date] IN 
                              (SELECT MAX([Last Contact Date]) 
                               FROM [Data].[dbo].[IAPT] 
                                WHERE t1.[Number] =  [Data].[dbo].[IAPT].[Number] 
                          AND 
      [Last Contact Date] NOT IN
                              (SELECT MAX([Last Contact Date]) 
                               FROM [Data].[dbo].[IAPT] 
                               WHERE t1.[Pseudo] =  [Data].[dbo].[IAPT].[Pseudo]))
```

The Table:

```
Pseudo  Number    Last Contact Date
0X1     18        17/06/2013
0X1     18        16/04/2013
0X2     19        25/04/2013
0X2     19        16/07/2013
```

Desired Result:

```
Number      Last Contact Date
1           16/04/2013
2           25/04/2013
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

You should use MIN function instead of MAX function

```
SELECT*
FROM
     [Data].[dbo].[IAPT] t1
WHERE
      [Last Contact Date] IN 
                              (SELECT MIN([Last Contact Date]) 
                               FROM [Data].[dbo].[IAPT] 
                                WHERE t1.[Number] =  [Data].[dbo].[IAPT].[Number] 
                          AND 
      [Last Contact Date] NOT IN
                              (SELECT MIN([Last Contact Date]) 
                               FROM [Data].[dbo].[IAPT] 
                               WHERE t1.[Pseudo] =  [Data].[dbo].[IAPT].[Pseudo]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a `PARTITION BY` clause:

```
SELECT Pseudo, Number, [Last Contact Date]
FROM (
  SELECT Pseudo, Number, [Last Contact Date],
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number 
                            ORDER BY [Last Contact Date]) AS rn
  FROM [Data].[dbo].[IAPT]) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

The first record within each `Number` partition is the one having the oldest date.

Answer (score 0):

This way simple

```
    SELECT  PSEUDO,  NUMBER , MIN ([LAST CONTACT DATE]) FROM [DATA].[DBO].[IAPT] T1
     GROUP BY PSEUDO,  NUMBER
```